# How to insert data to webform via HTTP/Drupal REST module?

Tags: webforms

I have hooked up a simple webform and now I need to insert data via HTTP/Drupal REST module ?

Is is possible to insert this way, else should I insert directly to DB ?

Comment: You want to use some data in a webform and know how to get that data?

Answer (score 0):

I used [webform_service](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_service) with [services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module to insert data in webform using REST and its working fine form me.